# Rails has_many association changes into parent model dont reflect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many

For example, i have this:

```
class Family < ActiveRecord::Base
  :has_many :members

  def aging(date)
    members.find_all_by_birthday(date).each do |m|
      m.age = m.age+1
      # i dont want to put a m.save here
    end
  end

  # some validations
end

@family = Family.first
@family.aging("2012-01-04")
@family.members.each do |m|
  puts m.age
end
# it still the old age
```

I would like to use @family.save after calling aging method but it seems to not work that way, i would like to save this only if all validations met. This is just an example to simplify what i need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `members.find_all_by_birthday(date)` does a separate query to return you a collection of members rather than fetching all members for the family into the association and then reducing it to the ones that have the corresponding birthday.

You can do:

```
members.select { |m| m.birthday == date }.each do |m|
  m.age = m.age + 1
end
```

Which will modify the members in place. It has the disadvantage of fetching them all from the database which the `find_all_by_birthday` doesn't as it just fetches the ones you want.

Comment: I'm not sure it's the *only* way. It is *a* way. You could do something much more sophisticated and override the `members` method on family but I think that'd be an overly complicated approach. Alternatively you could approach the problem from a different direction. Why can't the members be saved until the family is saved? Could both the saves be done within a transaction so that the changes happen together?

Comment: the problem is that i change a lot of attributes from 'family', and then i have an json integration with another server, if i dont get the response from the other server i cannot save the 'family', and using transaction i would have to take all the logic to the controller right?